# Are real numbers defined as Banach spaces?

Tags: soft-question, banach-spaces

I was listening to [this lecture by Norman Wildberger](https://youtu.be/6JjPA3msnbo), where he explains that real numbers are constructed as equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences. He never says that these equivalence classes are Banach spaces, but I was left wondering if that is what he means.

Comment: That is one of many ways to construct the real numbers. The equivalence classes are not even linear spaces.

Comment: The *set* of equivalence classes is (by definition) $\mathbb R$, and $\mathbb R$ is a vector space over itself and is a Banach space. But the individual equivalence classes are not. (The one that contains the zero sequence actually is a vector space over $\mathbb Q$, but none of the others are.)

Comment: Wildberger is best treated with caution. This particular video may be fine — I’ve not seen it — but Wildberger espouses some mathematical ideas that might politely be described as eccentric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real numbers can be defined by the process of completion with respect to the usual norm $\lvert\:\cdot\:\rvert:\Bbb{Q}\to \Bbb{Q}$. The norm $\lvert \:\cdot\:\rvert$ defines a metric on $\Bbb{Q}$ by $d(x,y)=\lvert x-y\rvert$. We note that $\Bbb{Q}$ is *not* complete with respect to this metric because there are Cauchy sequences which do not converge (this is the definition of not being complete): for instance the sequence
$$
3,3.1,3.14,3.141,3.1415,\ldots
$$
is "trying" to converge to $\pi= 3.1415...$ but $\pi$ is not rational so this does not make sense. [Note that one does not really know what $\pi$ is before defining $\Bbb{R}$ so this reasoning is sort of bad, but it is a good source of motivation - you could do the same thing with $\sqrt{2}$ or any infinite decimal expansion you wish.] The completion of $\Bbb{Q}$ with respect to this norm is called $\Bbb{R}$ and is defined to be the set of Cauchy sequences in $\Bbb{Q}$ modulo the relation that two Cauchy sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ are called equivalent if
$$
\lvert a_n-b_n\rvert\to 0
$$
as $n\to\infty$. Maybe this is already familiar to you. Anyway, the sequences themselves are not Banach spaces in any reasonable sense, but it is true that $\Bbb{R}$ has a norm defined by extending the norm $\lvert\:\cdot\:\rvert$ on $\Bbb{Q}$ from before. It is also true that the completion of a normed space with respect to a norm is complete (in that all Cauchy sequences converge). In particular, $\lvert\:\cdot\:\rvert$ extended from $\Bbb{Q}$ endows $\Bbb{R}$ with the structure of a complete normed vector space where we add Cauchy sequences by
$$
(a_n)+(b_n)=(a_n+b_n)
$$
and define scaling in the obvious way. So, $(\Bbb{R},\lvert\:\cdot\:\rvert)$ is a Banach space.

Answer (score 2):

This is unfortunately a nonsense question.

There is a *set* of Cauchy sequences. This *set* has a relation on it ($(a_n) \sim (b_n)$ if $\lim_n (a_n - b_n) = 0$). There is therefore a *quotient set* or *set of equivalence classes*.

None of this ever passes through anything with more structure than sets. (If you like, it passes through rings: the set of Cauchy sequences is a ring, because I know how to add and divide in it, and the relation respects these operations, so that the quotient inherits them.)

In fact "$V$ is a Banach space" does not even make sense until you invent the real numbers. A Banach space is a pair $(V, N)$, where $N: V \to \Bbb R_{\geq 0}$ is a function satisfying certain properties.